# Execute Treatements Before Returnig Table with a Table Valued Function?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a Table Valued Function , that use to return a Table ,result of an inner join :

```
ALTER FUNCTION  [dbo].[FT_GET_ListePreinscriptionUsagerActivite]
 (
     @UsagerID int
  )
  RETURNS TABLE 
  AS
  RETURN 
 (
  select TbReunion.Ident_Reunion, TbReunion.Intitule_Reunion,TbReunion.Date_Reunion,TbUsager.Nom_Usager,TbUsager.Prenom_Usager ,TbReunion.Heure_Deb_Rn,TbReunion.Heure_Fin_Rn , TbIntervenants.Nom_Employé  from TbReunion Inner Join TbParticipants on TbReunion.Ident_Reunion=TbParticipants.Ident_Reunion
                        Inner Join TbUsager on TbUsager.IdUsager = TbParticipants.Ident_Participant
                        Inner Join TbIntervenant_Formation on TbReunion.Ident_Reunion=TbIntervenant_Formation.Ident_Reunion
                        Inner Join TbIntervenants on TbIntervenants.Num_Employe=TbIntervenant_Formation.Ident_Intervenant
 where TbParticipants.Type_Participant=1 And  TbParticipants.Indic_Maj ='P' And TbUsager.IdUsager=@UsagerID and TbIntervenant_Formation.IdRole_Intervenant=42
  )
```

this function returns to me results as below :

```
id c2 
 1  a 
 1  b
 2  c
```

what i want is to get this type of result :

```
id c2
 1  a , b
 2  c
```

so  i need to commit some changes to the function as  this :

- store the result of the inner join into a table

  ```
   select * into newTable from (
   select TbReunion.Ident_Reunion, TbReunion.Intitule_Reunion,TbReunion.Date_Reunion,TbUsager.Nom_Usager,TbUsager.Prenom_Usager ,TbReunion.Heure_Deb_Rn,TbReunion.Heure_Fin_Rn , TbIntervenants.Nom_Employé  from TbReunion Inner Join TbParticipants on TbReunion.Ident_Reunion=TbParticipants.Ident_Reunion
                      Inner Join TbUsager on TbUsager.IdUsager = TbParticipants.Ident_Participant
                      Inner Join TbIntervenant_Formation on TbReunion.Ident_Reunion=TbIntervenant_Formation.Ident_Reunion
                      Inner Join TbIntervenants on TbIntervenants.Num_Employe=TbIntervenant_Formation.Ident_Intervenant
   where TbParticipants.Type_Participant=1 And  TbParticipants.Indic_Maj ='P' And TbUsager.IdUsager=@UsagerID and TbIntervenant_Formation.IdRole_Intervenant=42)
  ```
- concatenate the  rows that have the same id to get the expeceted result

  ```
   select Ident_Reunion,Intitule_Reunion,Date_Reunion,Nom_Usager ,Prenom_Usager, Heure_Deb_Rn,Heure_Fin_Rn,
   Nom_Employé=Stuff(
   (   
    SELECT  ', ' + Nom_Employé
     FROM newTable b 
     WHERE b.Ident_Reunion = a.Ident_Reunion 
    FOR XML PATH('')      
   )
    , 1, 2, '') from newTable a
   group  by Ident_Reunion,Intitule_Reunion,Date_Reunion,Nom_Usager ,Prenom_Usager, Heure_Deb_Rn,Heure_Fin_Rn
  ```

however when i do that i get errors :
   for

> select * into newTable from (
>   i get  ***"invalid use of an operator with side effects <> in a function"***

and  then for

> select Ident_Reunion,Intitule_Reunion,Date_Reunion ....
>   i get ***"selection statements included in a function cannot return data to a client"***

, so  i searched how i can solve that and  i found a type of table valued function called "Multi-statement table-valued functions " but even that function returns errors when i use it ?

so any idea on how to make some treatements before i return  results with table valued function ?

Comment: Don't use multi-line table-value functions; they perform awfully.

Comment: You say you get an error, but you don't tell us *what* that error is.

Comment: @Larnu the error  i get  on select is  : invalid use of an operator with side effects <<select>> in a function

Comment: Also, that function can *never* return that data set you say it does. You the function retrusn 2 columns, `id` and `c2`, however, neither column exists in your function. Your function has 8 columns. The expected results and function we have are completely unrelated.

Comment: @Larnu it's just an example to simplify things

Comment: But the example doesn't show the problem, so it doesn't help us. it like telling people you're having problems with a bicycle, and explaining the issue. Then you give them a motorcycle and expect someone to show you how to fix it there.

Comment: @Larnu that part of question isn't important , thats why i didn't detailed it , what is the question about is how to perform treatements in data before returning the  Table supposed to be  returned ,
and know to much but i think now if i need to make some treatements i should use a stored procedure rather than table valued function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by  changing the function to be a stored procedure , the errors disapperaed ,this is my working stored procedure  :

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [SP_GET_ListePreinscriptionUsagerActivite]
   @UsagerID int
  AS
  BEGIN


    drop table if exists newTable
        select * into newTable from (
        select TbReunion.Ident_Reunion, TbReunion.Intitule_Reunion,TbReunion.Date_Reunion,TbUsager.Nom_Usager,TbUsager.Prenom_Usager ,TbReunion.Heure_Deb_Rn,TbReunion.Heure_Fin_Rn , TbIntervenants.Nom_Employé  from TbReunion Inner Join TbParticipants on TbReunion.Ident_Reunion=TbParticipants.Ident_Reunion
                        Inner Join TbUsager on TbUsager.IdUsager = TbParticipants.Ident_Participant
                        Inner Join TbIntervenant_Formation on TbReunion.Ident_Reunion=TbIntervenant_Formation.Ident_Reunion
                        Inner Join TbIntervenants on TbIntervenants.Num_Employe=TbIntervenant_Formation.Ident_Intervenant
 where TbParticipants.Type_Participant=1 And  TbParticipants.Indic_Maj ='P' and TbIntervenant_Formation.IdRole_Intervenant=42) as view_table


 select Ident_Reunion,Intitule_Reunion,Date_Reunion,Nom_Usager ,Prenom_Usager, Heure_Deb_Rn,Heure_Fin_Rn,

 Nom_Employé=Stuff(
 (   
      SELECT  '| ' + Nom_Employé
       FROM newTable b 
       WHERE b.Ident_Reunion = a.Ident_Reunion 
      FOR XML PATH('')      
)
      , 1, 2, '') from newTable a
 group  by Ident_Reunion,Intitule_Reunion,Date_Reunion,Nom_Usager ,Prenom_Usager, Heure_Deb_Rn,Heure_Fin_Rn

  END
  GO
```

Comment: This SP performs DDL statements; you would never be able to do that in an function as you cannot perform DDL operations in them.